# Neat (bourbon.io) columns not matching up with outer container, is that right?

Tags: css, bourbon, neat

**Edit**: Updated the screenshot to match the markup
**Edit**: full markup is at https://gist.github.com/matgargano/68de587d905029bf3b29

I added `bourbon` and `neat` and set in my settings:

```
$visual-grid-opacity: 0.4;
$visual-grid-index: back;
$visual-grid-color: #000;
$visual-grid: true;
```

Then added:

```
.content-area {
    @include span-columns(9);
}

.widget-area {
    @include span-columns(3);
}
```

What shows up are 12 columns but my span-column: 9 only takes up ~6 and my 3 takes up ~3 but in the middle of my gutter.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: what is your markup?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, the markup is at: https://gist.github.com/matgargano/68de587d905029bf3b29

Comment: So it appears that it's *content* based.... since my content doesn't fill up the container, it doesn't align as expected.

Comment: can you please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? it's easy to do it with [sassmeister.com](http://sassmeister.com) in our case.